# Prevent the disappear of Dropdown menu using bootstrapDropdown when clicking on the list

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using using [bootstrap-dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) to generate a Dropdown menu. I would like to prevent the disappearing of the menu when click on it.

I have implemented the following code, but it does not work. Any idea how to fix it?

### HTML

```
<li class="dropdown notification">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="notification-label label label-info">
      <i class="icon-inbox icon-white"></i>
      <span class="notification-number">{{ unread_notifications }}</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu notification-list"></ul>
</li>
```

### JS

```js
events: {
  'click ul.notification-list': 'onClickNotification'
},

onClickNotification: function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try with `event.stopPropagation`?

```
onClickNotification: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e)
},
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable all auto closing of the dropdown you can just disable the listener

```
$('html').off('click.dropdown')
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVaqX/)

Comment: your answer sounds good. I did try it and it does not work. Are you sure? The view is rendered by using backbone but it should be not the issue because the code does not work also after render the page and typing your command in js console. Any idea?

Comment: @LorraineBernard I added a jsfiddle.  However, I'm thinking you'd prefer [@AntoJs's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743125/570918), since it only disables closing for clicks on the menu itself.

Comment: +1 yes you are right. Actually I would like also, in same condition, disable the appearing of menu. Any ideas how to make it without using  stopPropagation ?

Comment: Anyway any ideas why `$('ul.dropdown-menu').off('click.dropdown')​` in your jsfiddle does not work? how should I disable just a menu?

Comment: @LorraineBernard Let's chat about it instead of putting a bunch of comments in here: [Discussion on on/off](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14704/discussion-on-on-off)